# If the Dirichlet's eta function is conditionally convergent in the critical strip how can we ever compute its values there?

Tags: riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I'm studying infinite series, but I'm a physicist, not a mathematician.

I got it from Hardy's THE GENERAL THEORY OF
DIRICHLET'S SERIES that the Dirichlet series $\eta(s) = 1^{-s} - 2^{-s} + 3^{-s} - \dots$, with $s = \sigma + it$, converges for $\sigma > 0$, and converges absolutely for $\sigma > 1$, and so it converges only conditionally on the critical strip.

But, by Riemann's theorem, you can make a conditionally converging series converge to any value you like by finding some suitable rearrangement of terms.

So, how can we ever be sure of any value of $\eta(s)$ calculated inside the critical strip? For instance, if we calculate $\eta(s)$ at a non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)$, it gives us zero for one arrangement of terms, but may give a different value for other arrangments. Likewise, we may get a zero value for $\eta(s)$ at values of $s$ that are not actual zeros of $\zeta(s)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\eta(s)$ for ${\rm Re}(s) > 0$ is *defined* as an infinite series with terms ordered in the way you specified. That some theorem (namely the Riemann rearrangement theorem) says other rearrangements of the terms could give other values is irrelevant because those rearranged series are *not* defined as $\eta(s)$, and nobody cares about those other series for the purpose of working with $\eta(s)$.  It's sort of like asking how we can possibly know what $\pi$ is because moving the digits around (like changing 3.1415926535... to 3.4151295653...) leads to other numbers. Basically, so what? Such a change is introducing a distraction that has no importance to the object of actual interest.

It is true that the value of a conditionally convergent series is sensitive to the order of the terms while absolutely convergent series are not, but it's not as if a series being absolutely convergent is all we need to get good estimates on the value of the series. For example, the partial sums of the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^2$ converge absolutely but rather slowly (let's ignore the fact that we have a nice exact formula $\pi^2/6$).  There are series acceleration methods that can improve the rate of convergence of a transformed version of many infinite series, both absolutely and conditionally convergent ones.

In the case of $\eta(s)$, nobody would ever use the definition of $\eta(s)$ as an infinite series to do numerical computations with it.  Instead, express $\eta(s)$ in terms of the zeta-function:  $\eta(s) = (1 - 2/2^s)\zeta(s)$.
This is good because $\zeta(s)$ can be described by many kinds of formulas, including some rapidly convergent formulas involving integrals.

By the way, can you indicate why you are interested in $\eta(s)$?  It the reason is because you are interested in $\zeta(s)$, then focus on $\zeta(s)$ itself. The "accident" that $\eta(s)$ can be expressed by a series formula valid for ${\rm Re}(s) > 0$ when $\zeta(s)$ can't would not be a good reason for regarding $\eta(s)$ as more important or more interesting than $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Got it, the definition of $\eta(s)$ concerns an specific order (that's why I said I'm not a mathematician, that didn't cross my mind :), my interest on zetas and etas is, like I said, for studying series analytically and, also, as you said, for calculating them numerically (GNU MPFR). Good to know there are accelaration methods, it took more than 100 million terms for $\sigma =1/8$ to converge the first digit.

Comment: @Arc After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: At the same time, it's worth waiting a few days for more people to answer the question (potentially) rather than mark an answer as accepted less than an hour after the question was first posted.

Comment: @JitendraSingh, ok, answer accepted, thanks for letting me know, I'll read the rules better now.

Comment: @KCd, ops..., I should wait, true, but the fact is, I got it pretty clear now, thanks very much, the fact that summation order is part of the function definition is something you don't actually read in books... at least not the one's I've read.